# Couple issues with TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have a tableview with a uicollectionview within the cells that are loaded. I am currently running into two issues with tableview cells.

1) The first cell in the tableview is supposed to have a purple background, but it appears white on the initial load. I tried putting the code within the initializer, however that makes all of the cells loaded as cell 0 and thus every cell becomes purple; only when I put them in the draw() function do they correctly draw, with the exception of the first cell.

2) I am having an issue with the cells reloading incorrectly when they go off screen, what will happen is when the cells are put in the que, it messes up what the contents of the cells are and keeps redrawing them; I tried clearing the collectionView datasource and reloading it, but I can't seem to correctly do it; i just dont want the cells to keep being redrawn in the incorrect cells; so in other words in the first cell that is supposed to be solely purple, a collectionview will appear in the cell after it goes off screen. I am using prepareForReuse, but am not having any luck clearing the collectionview.

Here is the tableView Code for the cellForItem:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! DiscoverTVC
        print("The index path is \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.indexPathNum = indexPath.row
        return cell
}
```

Here is my customCell itself:

```
import UIKit

class DiscoverTVC: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var hasLoaded = false

    var collectionView : UICollectionView!
    var cellId = "Cell"
    var index = 0
    var indexPathNum = 0


    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.reloadData()

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        print(indexPathNum)

        /** Setting up labels in each TableView Cell **/
        let cellLabelHeader = UILabel()

        /** Collection View within the Tableview **/
        let flowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        /** The Indexing of cells within the TableView **/
        if indexPathNum == 0 {

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        } else

            if ((indexPathNum == 1) || (indexPathNum == 3)) {

                /** Setting up the Collection View within the Tableviews **/

                self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: self.bounds.width * 0, y: self.bounds.height / 3, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height / 1.8), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
                collectionView.register(DiscoverCVC.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
                collectionView.delegate = self
                collectionView.dataSource = self
                collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                self.addSubview(collectionView)

                index = indexPathNum



            } else

                if ((indexPathNum == 2) || (indexPathNum == 4)) {



                    /** Setting up the Collection View within the Tableviews **/

                    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:  self.bounds.width * 0, y: self.bounds.height / 8.5, width:  self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height / 1.15), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
                    collectionView.register(DiscoverCVC.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
                    collectionView.delegate = self
                    collectionView.dataSource = self
                    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    self.addSubview(collectionView)

                    index = indexPathNum


        }




    }



    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }




    /** Collection View Overloads **/

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DiscoverCVC

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        return cell
    }

    var width : CGFloat = 0

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        if index == 1 || index == 3 {
            width = (collectionView.bounds.height)
        } else {
            width = (collectionView.bounds.height) / 4
        }


        return CGSize(width:width, height:width)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



}
```

When the cell goes off screen & I return to it, the app crashes and says it unexpected found nil at: `collectionView.dataSource = self`

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh... You have too much going wrong there to address here. So - find and go through a few tutorials on re-using simple cells, then complex cells, then creating cells such as yours via code instead of storyboard prototypes, etc. Then start putting it all together. **While doing so...** If you come across a tutorial that tells you to instantiate and addSubview() *inside* `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)`? Never, ever go back to that website.

Comment: Do you have any resources I could use/research with?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really control, when `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` is invoked, so, you should create collection view in `func awakeFromNib()`, because it is invoked only one time for each cell. Background color you can change directly like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! DiscoverTVC
    print("The index path is \(indexPath.row)")
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If i use awakeFromNib how would I go about reseting the colletionView cells  within prepareForReuse so that they don't overlap and keep drawing?

Comment: So I tried putting the code within awakeFromNib and nothing is appearing in the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you create custom cell in Storyboard and use it. And setting color for cell do in in cellForRowAtIndexPath method like

if (indexPath.row == 0){cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple}